# Text indentation in unordered lists with CSS

Tags: css, list, styling, unordered

I have an unordered HTML list and am using CSS to style everything. When the text has multiple lines, it starts before the bullet point. Is there a way to make it start after the bullet point position?

[image]

Comment: Can you please post your HTML?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to use `list-style-position:outside` on your `<ul>`

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Madmartigan/TdYvu/1/)

Comment: in your example if i delete `list-style-position:outside` , then there is no effect on structure.

Comment: Many thanks, I was actually using list-style-position: inside; because I wanted to indent all the bullet points. When I use the outside value I can't seem to apply margin-left/padding-left to the ul/li anymore.

Comment: Yes, it is usually the default. `inside` will do what appears in OP's example.

Comment: @Frank Vilea: Must be something else in your css, it's working fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Madmartigan/TdYvu/7/). Mess around with the fiddle if you need to see how float, display properties, etc. affect it. I can't really say what the issue is without seeing code.

Comment: Thanks, I simply had to apply float: left; which is what I forgot and why it did not work previously.

Answer (score 1):

Please try and use this property

```
li {
    list-style-position:outside;
}
```

or inside one or the other. This should fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, easy enough.  Within your `<li>` do this:

```
<li>
  <div>Schnelles Importieren von Images As Planes</div> 
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks Kon. I tried it but it seems to cause problems with Firefox.

Comment: Well, you'll have to make some styling adjustments probably (e.g. margin, padding, display inline?)

Comment: Firefox would start the text on a new line for some strange reason. It used to be pure text so I forgot to apply float: left; to the new bullet point list which was the reason why all these values would not work.

Comment: Adding divs is more of a last resort when css solutions are available.

Comment: @Madmartigan, I'd say that's argumentative.  Depends on context of the problem.

Comment: @Kon: CSS is for styling documents. HTML is for describing what they contain. Adding a meaningless div into a list item to achieve a visual effect that is easily possible with CSS to me has no advantage or purpose, but I'd be willing to listen to opposition.

Comment: No, you're right for the most part.  I just wouldn't blindly apply CSS to everything without first considering if that's the appropriate solution for the problem at hand.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most condensed CSS, using the shorthand property syntax:

```
 ul {
    list-style: disk outside;
 }
```